# Adding self signing certificate to Java certificate manager as "Signer CA" breaks my applet (Win7 64bit)

Tags: java, security, applet, certificate

I am creating a Java applet which connects to SQLite database on the local file system. I've created a certificate for signing using keytool. I've signed every Jar file that I used and I can start the applet and it **works great** in Google chrome and IE.

I do get the standard Security warning dialog on which I have to click 'Ok' every time the page gets loaded but that's it. It works.

In an attempt to avoid this Security warning I've added the same certificate (via Java Control Panel) to the Signer CA certificate store. Now when browsing the page I do get the Security warning which allows me to check 'Do not ask me for the same publisher (or something like that)'. But the applet no longer works and I get the following list of exceptions in Java console

```
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions CeilingPolicy allPerms
security: SHA-256Certificate finger print: 7478E95FEAC103F0934BD2DDB669DE9A6105AD26ABA30C0C9F3A61107BFEBF4D
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/C:/Work/Projects/OP/SPA_Notes/web/web/java/SPA_NotesApplet.jar, version: null]
basic: exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.defineClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadAllowedCodebases(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getPermissions(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.getProtectionDomain(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
basic: Removed progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@175db37
security: Reset deny session certificate store
```

I am not really at home with either Java or its security settings so any help would be appreciated.

Just to repeat again: If I do not add the certificate to the "Signer CA" certificate store everything works fine. So I do not think that the signing of the JAR files is the problem. I am guessing that, either my self-created certificate is not suitable to be used as signer CA certificate, or its because there is no trust chain to verified CA (but I do not know why would this matter at all).